# VB.NET: how to reference a DataTable?

Tags: vb.net, reference

I am trying to reference a DataTable and I do not know how to achieve this. Please help and thank you very much.

In my code, I would like to assign dtTmp to dtTarget(i) through the reference dtCurr. Is it possible to achieve that in VB.NET?

```
Private dtA, dtB As DataTable

Dim dtTarget() As DataTable = {Me.dtA, Me.dtB}

For i As Integer = 0 To dtTarget.Length - 1

  dtTmp = New DataTable()
  'Do something to dtTmp

  'assign the new table to the reference
  dtTarget(i) = dtTmp      

Next
```

Answer (score 1):

`dtCurr = dtTmp` changes the reference of dtCurr, which is pointer you don't use later.
Try writing `dtTarget(i) = dtTmp` instead of your last line.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I should clarify my problem.

I have two private attributes:
Private dtA, dtB As DataTable

Then I start an array:
Dim dtTarget(1) = {Me.dtA, Me.dtB}

After running the code, the original Me.dtA and Me.dtB does not change. Using dtTarget(i) = dtTmp gives the same result.

Comment: I have edited my question, so you now know my actual problem. Thanks. :-)

Comment: Truth. That's not how references work.
 dtA still holds a reference to the original DataTable. You could try `dtA = dtTarget(1)`, but that's very roundabout.